# How do I get about making my Wordpress site make its data available via REST based web services?

Tags: php, web-services, wordpress

Do I just map URL to a function with mod rewrites or is there a better way?

Comment: What kind of data? What do you believe REST means? What URL style did you have in mind?

Comment: Wordpress already exposes multiple APIs: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some plugins: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=REST&sort=